# Getting mod_geoip to work with mod_wsgi in Apache 2.2.17

Tags: django, wsgi, geoip

I'd like to access the `GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE` environment variable from within Django running on mod_wsgi in daemon mode. The problem is, I can see the variable from within PHP scripts running on the server but it seems that it is not passed through WSGI to my Django site.
`request.META.get('GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE')` does not work.
Is there something like `WSGIPassAuthorization` for additional environment variables in mod_wsgi?

Comment: Where are you setting GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE in the first place? One can't answer the question without knowing where/how it is being set.

Comment: AFAICT it is set by mod_geoip inside Apache2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable is set by the extension module as an environment variable, then it will be accessible as:

```
import os
value = os.environ['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE']
```

Ie., just like any other environment variable.

---

UPDATE 1:

If set inside of an Apache module however such as mod_geoip, the only way it would be transfered into WSGI application realm is if it is set in req.subprocess_env of Apache request structure. Ie., the same as if SetEnv directive had been used with Apache. In that case it should appear in the WSGI environ dictionary passed to the WSGI application.

To try and validate whether this is occuring, using WSGI echo test script shown in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Displaying_Request_Environment

Comment: Tried that too, but `GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE` isn't included in the os.environ dict.

Comment: It seems that as of Django 1.3 the WSGi environ dict is merged into request.META, so now I can easily call request.META.get('GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE') to get the value i want.

Comment: I doubt that merging is only of as Django 1.3. You were always able to get access to the WSGI environ dictionary via the Django request object and I very much doubt they would have changed how that is done as it would have broken so many things which use what would have been the existing way of doing things.